Swapping touch digitizer from one Android phone to another
I have an IKALL K260 Android 6 phone with a faulty touch digitizer, a broken connector strap, and is irreparable, having IC SILEAD GSL1691. I want to replace that digitizer with Gionee F205's touch digitizer having IC Goodix 917D.
I have connected the pins in the same order, but it's not working. It (IC Goodix 617D) heats up and does not let the display glow. It seems like there is some driver-related issue, the phone may not have drivers for the new touch digitizer.
So, can anyone tell me, is it possible to add drivers through USB with a computer?

Drivers on Linux have to be compiled into the kernel or if the kernel supports modules a kernel module that was built for that specific kernel version.

Thanks for commenting

I figure out that IKALL K260 is a Unisoc device but Gionee F205 is an Mediatek device is it possible to flash phone with Mediatek firmware !

And what would you do with a phone that has a working digitizer but all the other components like display, sound, WiFi, cellular, gps, keys don't work because the drivers don't match the contained devices? What you would need is building/compiling a new kernel so that it contains all the drivers for the hardware components in your phone.

Since @Robert did not make it an answer, to complete off the question.  You cant just add a driver like you can on windows.  At least for the hardware integrated into the phone, the drivers are also integrated into the kernel.  Without looking at the two devices, it is unlikely that they would have the same pinout.
Seriously, Android 6 is way too old, maybe your money is better spent buying a newer second hand phone.
